# How do the evanescent waves contribute/cause a diffraction limit?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, diffraction, lenses

In the following [article](https://www.zhaowei.us/data/Journals/Nature%20Material%20_%20superlenses.pdf), under the section Physics of the Superlens, it is stated:

> The light emitted or scattered from an object includes not only
> propagating waves but also evanescent waves, which carry the
> subwavelength detail of the object. The evanescent waves decay
> exponentially in any medium with a positive refractive index so that
> they cannot be collected at the image plane by a conventional lens,
> and this results in a diffraction-limited image.

Why do the evanescent waves need to be collected? How do they cause the diffraction limit? Non-technical as well as technical answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose our object is described by the function $g(x,y,z=0)$. We can write this function as a superposition of plane waves (Fourier decomposition),
$$
g_{object}(x,y,z=0) = \iint df_x df_y \;G(f_x, f_y,z=0)e^{-2\pi i (f_x x + f_y y)}
$$
where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the spatial frequencies. Hence, the object consists of many different spatial frequencies.

Now, if we use the fact that any imaging system (=lenses) possesses a finite resolution, we  conclude that after propagating the distance $z$ some spatial frequencies, which were present in the object and thus in $G(f_x, f_y,0)$,  have vanished from the image. Hence, the propagation of the light changes the function $G(f_x, f_y,z)$ -- which is why we included the variable $z$. In fact, the free space propagator is given by
$$G(f_x, f_y,z)
=G(f_x, f_y,0) \cdot \exp{\left(
ikz\sqrt{1 - \lambda^2(f_x^2 + f_y^2)}
\right)}
$$
where you see that for large enough spatial frequencies the term under the square root becomes negative. These are the evanescent waves.

A full discussion can be found in the textbook from Goodman "Fourier Optics".